# Unable to generate correct namespace in generated XML

Tags: xml-parsing, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, sap-data-services

I am getting some extra lines in the namespace for the xml file generated by SAP BODS using the XSD file.

The below is my main XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
xmlns           = "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/customer/2006-10-31"
xmlns:xsd       = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace = "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/customer/2006-10-31"
elementFormDefault = "qualified">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="xml.xsd" />
```

The XML XSD is below:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!-- DOCTYPE xs:schema PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XMLSCHEMA 200102//EN" "XMLSchema.dtd" -->
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xml:lang="en">
```

The resulting XML top lines that I am seeing are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<!-- SAP Data Services generated XML -->
<!-- 2020-04-27.13:27:20(128,601)[1] -->
<ns1:customers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:ns1="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/customer/2006-10-31"
 xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
```

My expected result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/customer/2006-10-31">
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I don't see any semantic difference between the two, because both are the element `customers` of namespace `http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/customer/2006-10-31`. There is just a different way of expressing the element using different namespace **prefixes**, but only the corresponding namespace has a semantic meaning. Can you explain what you expect and why?

Comment: Thanks for your input Sandra.. Actually my target structure,i.e. Salesforce e-commerce does not accept the first one. So, I want my result without the ns1 namespace tag , exactly in the way desired. Can you please help on that?

Comment: I would say that Salesforce has a bug and you should tag your question with "Salesforce" along with the error message you obtain. You may also check all patches of Salesforce product or contact their support.

Comment: Isn't there a way to get rid of ns1 namespace and transform the xml or xsd?

Comment: what is the difference btw `main xsd` and `xml xsd`? describe your scenario. you are converting one xml to another?

Comment: The xml xsd is used in the import statement in the main xsd. I am not converting one xml into another. I am generating xml from xsd using sap bods , but the desired lines in the resultant xml is having ns1 namespace which I don't want.( The present result of xml and the expected xml is shown in the question)